# I want to update data table source data using jquery

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using Data table, and I have a Input column in data table. when I change some particular input box. it change front side. but I also wanted to update table source data and need to access that by Data Tables API methods later on here I tried some code, but its throw console undefined.

```
    $('#kwrdsTable').on('change', 'tr > td > input', function(e){

        var table = $('#kwrdsTable').DataTable();

        e.preventDefault();        
        const newValue   = parseFloat($(this).val());
        $(this).attr("value", newValue);

        console.log(table.cell(this).data(newValue));


    });
```

[image: first Image]
[image: second Image]

Comment: You say "**_in console it's undefined_**" but what is undefined...? Where does the error appear...?

Comment: console.log(table.cell(this).data(newValue));

Comment: in your code `this` is not a cell (a td) but an input. So your code `table.cell(this).data(newValue)` can't work

Comment: how to get data-table AIP source data row col index, my data table used pagination and orders.  console.log(table.cell($(this).closest('tr').index()) with this code I get tr index from HTML which index is deffrent from source data

Comment: Using the closest() function it's a good idea. But can you provide HTML code or screenshot with explanation...? Because it will be easier to understand what you want to do.

Comment: sure here I edited two Screenshot first one is HTML with data table and second is console.log( $('#kwrdsTable').DataTable());  here is second Screenshot you can see the Row index is different as its source data. In first screenshot I used peregrination and order be caused of that the row index is changed

Comment: I just see one screenshot (console screenshot)

Comment: @juan please look at my issue, I am stuck here is my work, is there any way or solution where I can update source of data table

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250866/discussion-between-juan-and-trada-lalit).

Comment: sugested by @Juan
        var table = $('#kwrdsTable').DataTable();
        var cell = table.cell( $(this).closest('td') )
        cell.data('<input id="traffic-capture-57" class="refreshable57" value="' + $(this).val() + '" style="width: 30%; background: none; border: none; text-align: center">%');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the chat, I'm not totally sure I understand how your site works but this piece of code can help you :)

```
$('#kwrdsTable').on('change', 'tr > td > input', function(e){

    var table = $('#kwrdsTable').DataTable();

    e.preventDefault();        
    const newValue   = parseFloat($(this).val());
    $(this).attr("value", newValue);
    
    // With this display you can obtain the cell containing the 'input' field
    console.log($(this).closest('td'));
    
    // And you can write in this cell with this code
    var cell = table.cell($(this).closest('td'));
    cell.data('Text for Test').draw();
});
```